# Recommendations regarding sharing model code in node.js and browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize as my server side ORM. Is there a recommended approach towards sharing the Model code (especially the validations) with my client application ?

Please don't recommend solutions which require me to move to a NoSQL database. Currently that is not an option for me. While I really Sequelize as an ORM, I am willing to move onto some other model implementation if it is beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persistencejs, but it doesn't appear to be as well maintained as Sequelize:

https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs

Comment: This is good to see new libraries filling up the gaps in Node.js ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

At present there does not seem to be an end to end solution ie. a model library which you could just require in either browser or server and define your models - where methods like save, update would be polymorphic requiring the developer to just extend standard model classes and use them on either client or server.

However, for people looking for a similar solution - I recommend using JSON schema validators, which are quite hassle free and provide a simple means to share your validation logic between client and server.